# NHibernate removing FK in one-to-many association on update

Tags: nhibernate

First, here is my relation

```
<class name="ServiceStep">
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="guid.comb"/>
</id>
 <set name="AdditionalInfoRows" cascade="save-update" >
  <key column="ServiceStepId"/>
  <one-to-many class="AdditionalInfoRow"/>
</set>
```

```
<class name="AdditionalInfoRow">
<id name="Id">
  <generator class="guid.comb"/>
</id>
<set name="AdditionalInfos" cascade="save-update" >
  <key column="AdditionInfoRowId"/>
  <one-to-many class="AdditionalInfo"/>
</set>
```

Now, when I create new ServiceStep and add AdditionalInfoRows into it, everything works fine and it's correctly persisted.

The problem is by update. I load ServiceStep and the Set is correctly loaded with AdditionalInfoRows. In my application I add new AdditionalInfoRows to this set. Then I call SaveOrUpdate on ServiceStep. Newly addes AdditionalInfoRows are persisted correctly but my original list looses the connection. FK in AdditionalInfoRows which should point to ServiceStep is set to NULL by NHibernate.

Hope somebody can point me into right direction.

Comment: The problem might that you aren't mapping the parent in the child mapping. You need to specify a property `ServiceStep` on `AdditionalInfoRow`, and specify which property of it is the foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try including something like this in your `AdditionalInfoRow` mapping:

```
<many-to-one name="ServiceStep" class="ServiceStep">
  <column name="ServiceStepId" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

to look like,

```
<class name="AdditionalInfoRow">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="guid.comb"/>
    </id>
    <set name="AdditionalInfos" cascade="save-update" >
    <key column="AdditionInfoRowId"/>
        <one-to-many class="AdditionalInfo"/>
    </set>
    <many-to-one name="ServiceStep" class="ServiceStep">
        <column name="ServiceStepId" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

Comment: I don't understand why this should help, but IT DID. Thnx :)

Comment: The problem is you did not specify that the child object `AdditionalInfoRow` had a property mapped to a foreign key column, so NHibernate would simply skip setting that column to `ServiceStepId`. Then, on retrieval the column would be empty.